# Where is convert in ImageMagick?

Tags: r, image, image-processing, gif, imagemagick-convert

I just spent an infuriating day trying to make a gif out of a series of jpg files in R. I installed ImageMagick to run the following code:

```
system("convert -delay 40 *.png example_4.gif")
```

but I get the following error message:

```
Warning message:
running command 'convert -delay 40 *.png example_4.gif' had status 4
```

which looks like a path error. Now I've looked for convert in the Imagemagick download and can't see it anywhere. Does anyone know where it is?

Alternately, is there another easier method of making a gif from a series of jpegs in R that isn't ridiculously long?

Thanks

Comment: Try replacing `convert` with `magick` if using v7+ - especially if on **Windows** and you didn't select *"Install legacy option"* when installing **ImageMagick**.

Comment: I've just tried that and it gives  a different error message: Warning message:
running command 'magick -delay 40 *.png example_4.gif' had status 127

Comment: I've just tried to get the legacy files option on install, but it doesn't give me the option to do that

Comment: I remember having this issue on windows. Unfortunately i cannot find my code now :(. I think solution was to specify full path to covert program

Comment: How about `magick convert`?

Comment: It would help if you told us what OS you are using and how you installed **ImageMagick**...

Comment: @Zindarod that gives the same 127 error as before

Comment: @MarkSetchell using windows 7 and installed this version: ImageMagick-7.0.7-0-Q16-x64-static. Using R in Rstudio

Comment: So, look in the directory where you installed Imagemagick and find the name of the full path to the program `magick.exe` and use that full path in your `system()` command.

Comment: just tried that and unfortunately no luck. Same 127 error.

Comment: Thanks all for the helpful comments, lots of suggestions so I'll have a go and let you know what works

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Three options:

1. Consider using the [`magick` R package](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/magick/index.html) instead of using `system()`.
2. Change your script from `convert ...` to `magick convert ...`.
3. Re-install imagemagick, and enable the "Install legacy utilities (e.g. convert)" option.

   [image]

This change has been around since 7.0.1 (now up to 7.0.7), and is discussed in their [porting guide](https://www.imagemagick.org/script/porting.php#cli), specifically in the section entitled "Command Changes".

Philosophically, I prefer to *not* install the legacy utilities, mostly because it can cause some confusion with command names. For instance, the non-ImageMagick `convert.exe` in windows tries to convert a filesystem ... probably not what you want to accidentally trigger (there is a very low chance that you could get the arguments right to actually make a change, but it's still not 0). The order of directories in your `PATH` will dictate which you are calling.

**EDITs**:

1. From comments, it seems like the difference between "static" and "dll" installers might disable the option to install legacy utilities such as `convert.exe`. So you can either switch to the "dll" to get the legacy option, or you are restricted to options 1 (`magick` R package) and 2 (`"magick convert ..."`).
2. From further comments (thanks to fmw42 and MarkSetchell), it is clear that the old `convert.exe` and the current legacy mode of `magick.exe convert` are not the same as the currently recommended `magick.exe` (without "convert"); the first two are legacy and compatibility modes, but they do not accept all arguments currently supported by `magick`-alone. So the use of `"convert"` anywhere in the command should indicate use of v6, not the current v7. This answer is then merely a patch for continued use of the v6 mechanisms; one could argue a better solution would be to use `magick.exe`'s v7 interface, completely removing the "convert" legacy mode.

Comment: is it possible to make a gif using the magick package? If so, what command would you use? Just looking at the documentation and haven't found it yet

Comment: interestingly I actually get a different 'select additional tasks' box that only gives me the first 4 and the last option (so not the legacy option)

Comment: The [`magick` vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/magick/vignettes/intro.html) is fairly complete, so I imagine it's possible. Since I don't create animated gifs like you are trying, I will take a cue from the "Animation" section that it should not be hard to do.

Comment: ok I've downloaded the dll installer and it works if you change the script to magick convert! Thanks!

Comment: Magick, magick convert and convert are all different. The proper command in IM 7 is magick. The others point to legacy IM 6 methods. You should either find the path to magick and preface it with the path or put the path into your Environment PATH variable, so that you are properly using IM 7 (unless you want to use legacy IM 6 code).

Comment: There is no indication that `magick convert` and `convert` will use different IM code. The porting guide suggests that these utilies (often symlinks) are identical in effect. There is no doubt that `magick` is the preferred command going forward. What indication do you have that these two commands will produce different results?

Comment: @r2evans `magick ...` and `magick convert ...` definitely **do** behave differently. Try `magick -size 100x100 xc:black -resize "%[fx:w*2]" a.jpg` to double the width of the image and it will be parsed and executed fine, but replace `magick` with either `convert` or `magick convert` and it will fail because the latter two implement v6 behaviour.

Comment: fmw42 and MarkSetchell, thanks, I stand corrected, thank you! (In this case, it isn't so much *"learn something new"* as *"unlearn something incorrect"*, but one of the two happens every day.) As salient as this point is, it doesn't necessarily change my answer: if you knowingly want the v6 behavior, then this is how you get it. If you want v7 behavior, you need to optionally translate from v6 to v7.