# convert and mogrify: The correct way to use them in modern versions of ImageMagick

Tags: windows, image-processing, imagemagick

To create an image thumbnail using an older version of ImageMagick, it was possible in the following ways:

*(To aid in futher referencing, examples are numbered.)*

```
1. convert.exe image.jpg -thumbnail 100x100 ./converted/converted_image.jpg
2. mogrify.exe -thumbnail 100x100 -path ./converted image.png
```

Now I have ImageMagick 7 (downloaded just yesterday), and during installation I intentionally turned *"Install legacy utilities (e.g. convert.exe)"* checkbox off. That is, I have only one utility in my ImageMagick directory: `magick.exe`.

I'm trying to understand what is the correct and future-proof way to perform above-mentioned operations according to modern ImageMagick versions.

A quote from https://imagemagick.org/script/porting.php#cli:

> `animate`, `compare`, `composite`, `conjure`, `convert`, `display`, `identify`, `import`, `mogrify`, `montage`, `stream`
>
> To reduce the footprint of the command-line utilities, these utilities are symbolic links to the `magick` utility. You can also invoke them from the `magick` utility, for example, use `magick convert logo: logo.png` to invoke the `magick` utility.

In the same source:

> With the IMv7 parser, activated by the `magick` utility, settings are applied to each image in memory in turn (if any). While an option: only need to be applied once globally. Using the other utilities directly, or as an argument to the `magick` CLI (e.g. `magick convert`) utilizes the legacy parser.

Hmm...

Works:

```
3. magick.exe convert image.jpg -thumbnail 100x100 ./converted/converted_image.jpg
4. magick.exe mogrify -thumbnail 100x100 -path ./converted image.png
```

Still works (the same way as `magick.exe convert`):

```
5. magick.exe image.jpg -thumbnail 100x100 ./converted/converted_image.jpg
```

However, the following one doesn't work (expected: should work the same way as `magick.exe mogrify`):

```
6. magick.exe -thumbnail 100x100 -path ./converted image.png
```

My question is: Which syntax should I use for `convert` and for `mogrify`? 3 and 4, or 4 and 5, or something different?

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46059611 (see Edit 2).

Answer (score 19, accepted):

AFAIK, and I am happy to add any corrections suggested, it works like this.

The first idea is that you should use version 7 if possible and all the old v6 commands, **WITH THE EXCEPTION OF** `convert` should be prefixed with `magick`. That means you should use these

```
magick ...                # in place of `convert`
magick identify ...       # in place of `identify`
magick mogrify ...        # in place of `mogrify`
magick compare ...        # in place of `compare`
magick compose ...        # in place of `compose`
```

If you use `magick convert` you will get old v6 behaviour, so you want to avoid that!

Furthermore, v7 is more picky about the ordering. You must specify the image you want something done to **before** doing it. That means old v6 commands like:

```
convert -trim -resize 80% input.jpg output.jpg
```

must now become:

```
magick input.jpg -trim -resize 80% output.jpg     # magick INPUT operations OUTPUT
```

---

So, looking specifically at your numbered examples:

1. Should become:

   `magick image.jpg -thumbnail 100x100 ./converted/converted_image.jpg`
2. Should become:

   `magick mogrify -thumbnail 100x100 -path ./converted image.png`
3. invokes old v6 behaviour because you use `magick convert` instead of plain `magick`, and should be avoided
4. Is correct, modern syntax
5. Is correct, modern syntax
6. Looks like you meant `magick mogrify` because you didn't give input and output filenames and because you use `-path`, but it looks like you accidentally omitted `mogrify`. If you didn't accidentally omit `mogrify`, then you probably meant to use the old `convert`-style command, and need an input and an output file and you need to specify the input file before the `-thumbnail`.

**Keywords**: Usage, wrong, modern, v7 syntax, prime.

Comment: "Furthermore, v7 is more picky about the ordering. You must specify the image you want something done to before doing it." - For `mogrify`, it still must be `magick mogrify -format jpg image.png`, not `magick mogrify image.png -format jpg`, right? The second version doesn't work for me.

Comment: Yes, AFAIK, the files for mogrification come at the right-most end of the command like outputs.

Comment: @MarkSetchell Your answer is great! What about `magick-script`?

Comment: @Imat-ReinstateMonica There are examples of `magick-script` here https://stackoverflow.com/a/75711947/2836621 and here https://stackoverflow.com/a/77318098/2836621