# Trying to convert Magick to a .Bat to drag and drop

Tags: image, batch-file, imagemagick

So I have this `320x320` pixel file called `player0.bmp`. I want to cut into `32x32` pixel `.bmp` files. I can run a `cmd.exe` prompt, change directory to the directory of the file, and run this command;

```
magick convert player0.bmp -size 320x320 -crop 32x32 player0-%02d.bmp
```

This script works, it breaks up the image into exactly what I want. But having to change the name of the file in the command for hundreds of files is something I'd like to avoid. Is there any way I can create a `.bat` file to do this without having to change the scripted file name and output file name?

I want to be able to just drag and drop `Item0.bmp` onto the `.bat` file and have it spit out `Item0-01.bmp` through `Item0-99.bmp`, then be able to drag and drop `Item1.bmp` and have it come out as `Item1-01.bmp` through `Item1-99.bmp`.

Any help to make this `.bat` file would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Try to avoid `magick convert ...` and just use plain `magick ...` See here for explanation https://stackoverflow.com/a/61208844/2836621

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I really don't use Windows, and have no way of testing this but, AFAIK, when you drop a file on a Windows batch file it receives the filenames as parameters, so you will probably want something along these lines:

```
magick "%~1" -size 320x320 -crop 32x32 "%~dpn1-%%02d.bmp"
```

because I *"think"* `%~dpn1` expands to the full name without the extension. Please only try this on non-critical files as I am not able to test it at all. You probably also want more error checking and maybe handling of multiple filenames as well so you can drop 2 or more files on your script...

Comment: Yes, `%~dpn1` is the full path without extension. Anyway, you should use `"%~1"` rather than `%1` to grant proper quotation. Any you will have to double the `%`-sign in `%%02d` so that one literal such character is passed over to the `magick` command...

Comment: @aschipfl Thank you for putting me right. Maybe you could check my edit is correct please? Thank you.

Comment: You're welcome! I can't test it since I don't have `magick`, but it looks correct to me...

Comment: Tried it on Windows 10 and IMv7.0.10. This command saved as a Windows BAT script should work exactly as expected.

Comment: Thank you very much for the help!

Answer (score 3):

This Windows BAT script using ImageMagick v7 will take a drag-and-dropped file as an input image, crop it into 32x32 pixel pieces, and write the output files using the input file name plus three digit sequential numbering like "inputfile_000.bmp", "inputfile_001.bmp", "inputfile_002.bmp", etc.

```
@echo off

pushd "%~dp1"

magick "%~1" ^
   -set filename:0 "%%[t]" ^
   -size 320x320 ^
   -crop 32x32 ^
      "%%[filename:0]_%%03d.bmp"

popd

exit /b
```

It starts by changing to the directory of the drag-and-dropped input image, and writes the output files there. You should be able to drop your input file on the actual BAT file or even on a shortcut located somewhere other than the directory of the BAT script *or* the input image.

Note the doubling of percent signs is required in *most* cases in a BAT script.

Tested this on Windows 10 with IMv7.0.10, and by changing "magick" to "convert", it also works with IMv6.9.10.

Comment: I'm intrigued as to why you choose to do it by changing directory? Do you have a moment to explain please?

Comment: I have a couple utility scripts like that with a shortcut on the desktop and the script somewhere else. When I drag and drop from a file explorer window onto the shortcut, I want the command to change to the directory of the input image so it creates the output files there instead of where the script or the shortcut lives.

Comment: Oh, ok thank you. Do you know if my version works please? I'll delete it if not. I expected that the input and output paths would be fully described by the parameters I used.

Comment: Yessir. I saved your command as "testme.bat" and dropped a small image on it. Works exactly as intended.

Comment: Excellent - thank you very much for making time for me.

Comment: Thank you very much for the help!