# How to draw a image on top of a shape

Tags: imagemagick, imagemagick-convert

**Simplified example:**

I do create a cirlce like following:

```
magick convert -size 256x256 xc:none -fill #FFFFFF -draw "circle 128,128 256,128" +profile "icc" out.png
```

And I do convert a given image like following:

```
magick convert in.png -background none -gravity center -resize 181x181 +profile "icc" out.png
```

**Question:**

In my examples above I do have following "core" functions:

- `-size 256x256 xc:none -fill #FFFFFF -draw "circle 128,128 256,128" +profile "icc"`
- `in.png -background none -gravity center -extent 181x181 +profile "icc"`

How can I combine those images WITHOUT saving the first one to a temporary file? I want to create a 256x256 output image, draw the circle to this image and then draw the converted input image on top of the circle (centered).

**My current solution**

Create 2 different images and combine them like following:

```
 magick convert -composite -gravity Center out1.png out2.png out.png
```

**EDIT - FULL EXAMPLE**

PS Script looks like following:

```
$in = ".\in.png"
$out1 = ".\tmp1.png"
$out2 = ".\tmp2.png"
$out = ".\out.png"

// 1) create circle image
magick convert -size 256x256 xc:none -fill #FFFFFF -draw "circle 128,128 256,128" +profile "icc" PNG32:$out1

// 2) convert input image
magick convert $in -background none -gravity center -resize 181x181 +profile "icc" -colorspace Gray -fill "#E91FCB" -colorize 50 PNG32:$out2

// 3) combine circle + converted image
magick convert -composite -gravity Center $out1 $out2 PNG32:$out

// 4) delete temp. images
Remove-Item $out1
Remove-Item $out2
```

Input Image:

[image]

Output Image (not visible, but it has the white circle as background + a transparent background otherwise):

[image]

Comment: Please include your input image `in.png` or something representative in terms of size/colour. And the expected output image. Please note that `magick convert ...` is nearly always wrong. It is just `magick ...` without `convert`.

Comment: I added a full example... I don't know why you need that - my question is a syntax question and not about help with the script itself. I don't know what you want to say with the second sentence - `magick convert` works for me, should I use `magick` only?

Comment: **ImageMagick** v7 introduced `magick` as the name of the command to avoid using lots of command namespace with `identify`, `convert`, `mogrify`, `compose`, `compare`, `stream` and to avoid clashes with Windows `convert` which converts filesystems to other formats. If you use `magick convert ...` it will give you old, v6 behaviour which you should avoid when you clearly have v7. I explained it all here https://stackoverflow.com/a/61208844/2836621

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use parenthesised processing like this:

```
magick -size 256x256 xc:none -fill white -draw "circle 128,128 256,128" \( in.png -background none -gravity center -resize 181x181 -colorspace Gray -fill "#E91FCB" -colorize 50 \) -composite result.png
```

[image]

On Windows, omit the `\` before parentheses.