# Retain embedded metadata when resizing DPX in Imagemagicks

Tags: image, image-processing, imagemagick, metadata

I'm attempting to do a batch resize on a DPX sequence using the following Imagemagicks command:

```
magick test.dpx -resize 2076x1186 test_2k.dpx
```

However, when I do, various pieces of the embedded metadata get changed. Results below:

```
Original: dpx:film.count: 8350
dpx:film.format: 003F
dpx:film.frame_position: 86410
dpx:film.frame_rate: 24
dpx:film.id: 02
dpx:film.offset: 08
dpx:film.prefix: 048832
dpx:film.shutter_angle: nan
dpx:film.type: 07`

Modified: dpx:film.count: 835
dpx:film.format: 003F
dpx:film.frame_position: 86410
dpx:film.frame_rate: 24
dpx:film.held_count: 0
dpx:film.id: 0
dpx:film.offset: 0
dpx:film.prefix: 04883
dpx:film.sequence_extent: 0
dpx:film.shutter_angle: nan
dpx:film.type: 0
```

This is causing the edgecode to be read incorrectly by Davinci Resolve. Am i doing something wrong?

Comment: Have you correctly pasted the values in your question? There seem to be some unlikely differences. Do you know which specific metadata change is causing your problems? Can you share your DPX file - Dropbox, Google Drive or similar as `imgur` won't accept such beasts. Note by the way that magick convert ... is pretty much always wrong https://stackoverflow.com/a/61208844/2836621

Comment: @MarkSetchell Yes I can confirm that the values are pasted correctly, it looks like various fields are missing their last character/byte. Keycode/Edgecode is made up of a combination of film id, offset, type, and prefix. I tried using just Magick instead of Convert, same result. I also tried some different DPX files, same result.

Comment: Here are the original and converted DPXs: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1F9hI9I8pyZ2BjM-vag-gcKckl4ldSIqR?usp=sharing

Comment: Found a workaround by using GraphicsMagick instead of ImageMagick, so i'm putting this down to a possible bug in ImageMagick.

Comment: What exact version of Imagemagick?

Comment: @fmw42 Version: ImageMagick 7.0.11-6 Q16 x86_64 2021-04-03

Comment: Please report this problem on the Issues forum in the Imagemagick GIT web site at https://github.com/ImageMagick/ImageMagick/issues. Identify your Imagemagick version and platform/OS along with your issue

Comment: @fmw42 Done! Ticket is here: https://github.com/ImageMagick/ImageMagick/issues/3537

Comment: Thank you. I saw it I suspect it is just truncating in the listing and not an error in the computation. The listing is probably a fixed length field. But the Imagemagick developers will look into it when they can.