# ImageMagick script fails with MISLEADING filename or extension too long (-sparse-color)

Tags: imagemagick, imagemagick-convert

**Problem**

In my quite short script I have the problem that it sometimes reports that the filename or extension is too long. Depending on the `$image` and `$size` values in my script this error may occur or not.

E.g. the script below produces this error with the image from [here](https://wallpaperaccess.com/full/138728.jpg) - saved and converted to "example3.png".

I do use Version: ImageMagick 7.0.10-62 Q16 x64 on windows and I don't know what to do with the error message... Any ideas what the problem is here?

**Powershell script**

```
#####################
# Setup
#####################

$image = "./example3.png"
$out = "./result.png"
$outPalette = "./palette.png"

$size = 50
$fuzz = 50
$colors = 6
$resizedSize = "$($size)x$($size)`!"
$histogramSize = "$($size)x$($size)"

#####################
# Program
#####################

Write-Host ""

# 1) Scale + change depth + remove unwanted colors (b/w)
Write-Host "- Step 1..." -ForegroundColor Green
magick convert $image -scale $resizedSize -depth 8 `
    -fuzz $fuzz -transparent black -transparent white `
    $out

#2) create histogram with the help of the sparse colors
Write-Host "- Step 2..." -ForegroundColor Green
$dataHistogram = magick convert -size $histogramSize xc: -sparse-color voronoi ( magick convert $out sparse-color: ) +dither -colors $colors -depth 8 -format %c histogram:info:

# ... more ...
```

**Edit: Adjustments**

- replaced `magick convert` with `magick`
- replaced `$fuzz = 50` with `$fuzz = "50%"`
- replaced `$size = 50` with `$size = 100`

More images do work now but e.g. following still fails with the same error:
[image]

**Edit2:**

The result of the inner magick command (`magick convert $out sparse-color:`) looks like following:

```
# ImageMagick pixel enumeration: 100,100,255,srgba
0,0: (87,72,86,0)  #57485600  srgba(87,72,86,0)
1,0: (105,81,91,0)  #69515B00  srgba(105,81,91,0)
...
```

Comment: Note that `magick convert ...` is nearly always wrong https://stackoverflow.com/a/61208844/2836621

Comment: Note that `-fuzz` is best used with a **percentage** rather than an absolute value since `red +/- 50` is very different on an 8-bit image in the range 0..255 relative to `red +/-50` on a 16-bit image in the range 0..65535.

Comment: thanks - seems like my value for fuzz was the problem... first tests show that using 50% (I wanted that actually) solves the issue

Comment: @MarkSetchell I made the adjustments you mentioned and have added this information to my question - I still see this error now, any further thoughts?

Comment: Can you edit the actual error message into your question please? Also, I don't know `powershell` syntax. I presume `magick ...(magick ...)` runs the outer `magick` command using the results of the inner `magick` command? If so, can you separate out the results of the inner `magick` command please - just for debug purposes.

Comment: The full error message is "Error executing magick.exe: the filename or extension is too long" (translated). And yes, your presumption is correct. The result of the inner command is added to my question. I know the result does not look like what the docs say that I should pass to the `-sparse-color` command but it still works... I also tried to convert the data to the format `x,y #COLOR  x,y #COLOR ...` but that won't work either because I will hit the maximum length of command line arguments in this case...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure what's going on with `powershell` but if the issue is the length of the command-line, you can supply the sparse colour from a file like this:

```
magick -size 800x600 xc: -sparse-color voronoi @colors.txt result.png
```

Or on `stdin` like this:

```
echo "10,10 red 200,200 yellow" | magick -size 800x600 xc: -sparse-color voronoi @- result.png
```

Comment: actually, I tried this. I even tried it on the command line, but I can't find a syntax that works on windows. E.g. following works: `magick -size 100x100 xc: -sparse-color voronoi "0,0 #57485600 1,0 #69515B00 2,0 #78566000 3,0 #835E6700 4,0 #95666F00" test.png`. Putting the EXACT same text from this command into a text file and run `magick -size 100x100 xc: -sparse-color voronoi @colors2.txt test.png` will fail with `invalid number of Arguments @error/operations.c/SparseColorOptions/252`...

Comment: thanks for your patience and for taking the time to help - I found out why supplying my data via a file did not work - I forgot to define a proper encoding when exporting it. Encoding it as UTF-8 or ASCII and reading it via `@colors.txt` works