# Confused about -quality setting in Imagemagick

Tags: imagemagick, imagemagick-convert

With Imagemagick, I compress and resize in batch my JPEG images with the command:

```
magick convert 3840x2160.jpg -resize 1366 -format jpeg -sampling-factor 4:2:0 -strip -quality 70 -interlace JPEG -colorspace RGB -write 1366.jpg
```

Please note that **I set -quality with a range from 0 to 100**, as I've seen others do.

Now, I've found [this tutorial](https://www.neutssoftware.com/imagemagick/imagemagick_compress_and_quality_options.html)
Where it says:

> The -quality option has the following format and is used mainly for
> the JPEG family compression type:
>
> -quality value
>
> For the value we can place numbers between 0 (poor quality) and 10
> (high quality). If you don't use the -quality option in your commands
> then the quality of the input image is used for processing or the
> value of 7.5 is used.

Quality must be specified **between 0 and 10**, it says.

So, which method is the right one?
**Between 0 and 10**, or **between 0 and 100** as I've seen others do?

Comment: The range use for `-quality` depends on the fileformat used, see (the docs): http://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php#quality

Comment: The link referred to by @Luuk is correct. Range 0..10 is **incorrect** for JPEG. Also `magick convert ...` is pretty much always wrong, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/61208844/2836621

Comment: Also `-write` is superfluous in your command as it writes the output to the last filename on the command-line anyway. Also, `-format JPEG` is superfluous as it is inferred from the output filename and is mainly useful when using `magick mogrify ...` when no output file is directly specified.

Comment: So, if I understand correctly, for JPEG -quality is 1 to 100, is that so? Also, what about Webp -quality?

Comment: If you run `identify -list delegate | grep -i webp` you can see that **ImageMagick** passes the quality setting you define on the command-line straight through to `cwebp` - the Google tool for creating WEBP files. So it does whatever their `cwebp` does. `png<= webp      "cwebp' -quiet -q %Q '%i' -o '%o"`