# Adding watermark to image using ActiveStorage and MiniMagick

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, imagemagick, rails-activestorage, minimagick

I am using Rails 6 ActiveStorge and MiniMagick to uplaod and resize images. Now I am trying to add a watermark to the image and am using:

```
<%= image_tag file.variant(draw: "image Over 0,0 10,10 '#{image_url('logo-mini.jpg')}'") %>
```

But the error I get is:

```
MiniMagick::Error (`magick convert /var/folders/2v/s0lfxd5d1lz6dhp9c4j8r8jr0000gn/T/ActiveStorage-110-20220903-1940-19jj9m8.jpeg[0] -auto-orient -draw image Over 0,0 10,10 'http://localhost:3000/assets/logo-mini-31a22ba47ac39efe669de611e397a51d52826f578ba47922492bcf2371c00b02.jpg' /var/folders/2v/s0lfxd5d1lz6dhp9c4j8r8jr0000gn/T/image_processing20220903-1940-d5ua9e.jpeg` failed with error:
convert: unable to open file `http://localhost:3000/assets/logo-mini-31a22ba47ac39efe669de611e397a51d52826f578ba47922492bcf2371c00b02.jpg' @ error/draw.c/DrawPrimitive/5616.
convert: non-conforming drawing primitive definition `image' @ error/draw.c/RenderMVGContent/4493.
```

I have tried all kinds of image urls, paths, https etc but always the same error. Any ideas on what might be wrong?

Comment: I don't know, or use, minimagick, but note the following. You do not want `magick convert INPUT ... OUTPUT`, just use plain `magick INPUT ... OUTPUT` See https://stackoverflow.com/a/61208844/2836621

Comment: Also, the syntax needs quotes around what you are drawing, i.e. `magick INPUT -draw "image over ... 'http:xxx'" OUTPUT`