# ImageMagick output files differ between manual or batch run

Tags: batch-file, cmd, imagemagick

I have 4 files `scan*.jpg` in a directory and split them into 50% wide images with 4 separate commands in the command prompt:

```
magick convert -crop 50%x100% scan0000.jpg output0000.jpg
magick convert -crop 50%x100% scan0001.jpg output0001.jpg
magick convert -crop 50%x100% scan0002.jpg output0002.jpg
magick convert -crop 50%x100% scan0003.jpg output0003.jpg
```

The result is as expected:

```
04/10/2022  18:41           747.709 scan0000.jpg
04/10/2022  18:41         1.382.076 scan0001.jpg
04/10/2022  18:41         1.646.004 scan0002.jpg
04/10/2022  18:41         2.204.373 scan0003.jpg
04/10/2022  21:08            75.856 output0000-0.jpg
04/10/2022  21:08           559.131 output0000-1.jpg
04/10/2022  21:08           566.601 output0001-0.jpg
04/10/2022  21:08           694.210 output0001-1.jpg
04/10/2022  21:09           700.709 output0002-0.jpg
04/10/2022  21:09           797.154 output0002-1.jpg
04/10/2022  21:09         1.069.680 output0003-0.jpg
04/10/2022  21:09           940.720 output0003-1.jpg
```

But if I put these same 4 commands in a `doit.bat` or `doit.cmd` and run that, I get 7000+ small files:

```
04/10/2022  21:10             1.438 output0000-0.jpg
04/10/2022  21:10             1.627 output0000-1.jpg
04/10/2022  21:10               902 output0000-10.jpg
04/10/2022  21:10               289 output0000-100.jpg
04/10/2022  21:10               289 output0000-1000.jpg
04/10/2022  21:10               289 output0000-1001.jpg
[snip]
04/10/2022  21:10               289 output0000-99.jpg
04/10/2022  21:10             1.253 output0000-990.jpg
04/10/2022  21:10             1.535 output0000-991.jpg
04/10/2022  21:10             2.173 output0000-992.jpg
04/10/2022  21:10               507 output0000-993.jpg
04/10/2022  21:10               348 output0000-994.jpg
04/10/2022  21:10               660 output0000-995.jpg
04/10/2022  21:10               289 output0000-996.jpg
04/10/2022  21:10               289 output0000-997.jpg
04/10/2022  21:10               289 output0000-998.jpg
04/10/2022  21:10               289 output0000-999.jpg
04/10/2022  21:10             2.664 output0001-0.jpg
04/10/2022  21:10             1.960 output0001-1.jpg
04/10/2022  21:10             1.718 output0001-10.jpg
04/10/2022  21:10               922 output0001-100.jpg
04/10/2022  21:10               328 output0001-1000.jpg
04/10/2022  21:10               331 output0001-1001.jpg
[snip]
04/10/2022  21:10               289 output0003-997.jpg
04/10/2022  21:10             2.351 output0003-998.jpg
04/10/2022  21:10             3.015 output0003-999.jpg
```

How come and how can I prevent this? (I have to convert several batches of 50 files.)

This is on Windows 11.

Comment: Why do you have hashes (`#`) in your commands? In Windows batch files you need to double up percent signs to escape them.

Comment: @MarkSetchell Stupid typo - I just corrected it and *that* makes no difference, but if I then double percent it, it works. Should I leave the question (without the hashes) so you can write an answer?

Comment: `magick convert ...` is nearly always not what you want, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/61208844/2836621 Did you delete output files from previous run first?

Comment: Please click [edit] and show the actual batch file you are running. Thank you.

Comment: I believe that Windows .bat files need percents doubled.

Comment: @fmw42 You should make that an answer, because as a comment it can be overlooked, while it is the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

fmw42 and Mark Setchel [both](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73952689/imagemagick-output-files-differ-between-manual-or-batch-run/74363536#comment130576959_73952689) [commented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73952689/imagemagick-output-files-differ-between-manual-or-batch-run#comment130577514_73952689) with what was essentially the answer, so I'm adding it as an answer here:

The % signs need to escaped (doubled) when copying those command lines into  the batch file:

```
magick convert -crop 50%%x100%% scan0000.jpg output0000.jpg
magick convert -crop 50%%x100%% scan0001.jpg output0001.jpg
magick convert -crop 50%%x100%% scan0002.jpg output0002.jpg
magick convert -crop 50%%x100%% scan0003.jpg output0003.jpg
```