# How to flip a dng image?

Tags: image, imagemagick

I need to flip 1400 dng images horizontally, eg along a vertical axis, so that left becomes right as in a mirror.

With imagemagick, it works well with tif images, using "magick convert -flop". But on dng, there is a tricky delegation issue because of an outdated dng lib.

Is there another way to do it or should I solve this delegation issue (this is a one-time need)? I feel that others would find helpful to find an documented alternative.

I have tried quite a few utilities (cli and gui, linux and windows) but none allows the flipped image to be saved as dng. In Digikam for example, the flip is only a flag, the pixels are not flipped. In others, one needs to save as tif or jpg.

Comment: `magick convert` is almost never what you want... https://stackoverflow.com/a/61208844/2836621

Comment: Nobody and no tools seem to want to write DNG as there are so many and such varied parameters and values that could be embedded and that would need to be copied forward from the input DNG to the output DNG. As you say **ImageMagick** doesn't support it, and you can see that by running `magick identify -list format | grep DNG` and see there is only an `r` (for `read`) and no `w` (for `write`) beside it.

Comment: In the grand scheme of things, DNG files (like other raw sensor formats) are read-only and shouldn't be altered. You flip the image when it is converted/demosaiced, by looking at the Exif orientation flag (unless you copy that flag to the output file). This is not different from handling portrait/landscape orientation. In your case changing the Exif flag should be enough since the conversion downstream should use it if set.

Comment: If you share one of your DNGs (via Dropbox or Google Drive) I may be able to flip the orientation and you can see if it works downstream for you.

Comment: Thank you @MarkSetchell for your looking into this, I'm grateful. Let me some time to read the docs you pointed out to me. I considered using only flags at first but I encountered issues since several software don't take them into account. For example, Silverfast HDR ; The annoyance is that I can't tell when the orientation is ok or not without comparing to the dng. Familiar faces appear weird when a photo is flipped.

Comment: I'd need a DNG from you to test with as I don't have any - only Sony ARW files.

Comment: Oh, thanks a lot to go the extra mile! Here is a link:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1duNIKHk8TRW0hQca59Kk_JvfKwxxnCV9/view?usp=share_link  [fish being sold on a pier, Florianopolis, Brazil, 1975]

Answer (score 0):

I can't test this with your downstream processing software, and it may well ignore the flag I am setting, but here's what I have for what it's worth.

If you use `exiftool` you can extract the *"orientation"* like this:

```
exiftool -orientation  C02-322.dng 
Orientation                     : Horizontal (normal)
```

Or if you go numeric instead of interpreted:

```
exiftool -n -orientation  C02-322.dng 
Orientation                     : 1
```

Then you can set the orientation. I set it to `2` or *"mirrored horizontal"* like this:

```
exiftool -IFD0:Orientation#=2 C02-322.dng
```

The values you can try are specified [here](https://www.awaresystems.be/imaging/tiff/tifftags/orientation.html).

I then checked again with:

```
exiftool -orientation  C02-322.dng
Orientation                     : Mirror horizontal
```

I have no idea whether your downstream processing will respect this. The modified version of the file is of identical length, so I guess all your existing DNG data has been carried forward correctly.

Comment: Interesting lead! I'll look into it in the coming days and will come back to let you know. Thanks a lot for your time and knowledge on the matter, it's super helpful.