# Installing imagemagick using homebrew -- can't find command

Tags: imagemagick, homebrew

I tried installing imagemagick using homebrew on a Mac. Specifically, I did:

```
brew install imagemagick
```

in terminal. There were no error messages. When I go to use imagemagick, e.g. using the command:

```
magick convert
```

I don't see the magick command available when I try to tab complete. I'm a bit uncertain how to debug this -- it seems like it should have installed fine?

Comment: What do you get from "magick -version"?  Also in general, use magick, not magick convert. Imagemagick is a command line program. Your command is not a full command. It does nothing without an input and output image specified,

Answer (score 1):

As part of installing **homebrew** you need to set your PATH so your shell knows where the executable binaries are installed.

Depending on your homebrew version and macOS hardware and software, you may need:

```
export PATH=/opt/homebrew/bin:$PATH
```

or

```
export PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH
```

You can tell which of the two commands above you need with:

```
find {/opt/homebrew,/usr/local}/bin -name magick
```

Then run:

```
hash -r
```

and all **homebrew** commands like `magick` should work for your current session.

---

If you want the PATH set correctly for all future sessions you will need to add the `export` command from above to your login profile. That will depend on your shell, but is probably:

```
$HOME/.zprofile
```

or

```
$HOME/.profile
```

---

Note that you should read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61208844/2836621) to understand why you do NOT want to use `magick convert`.