# Transparent Background - shows as black (convert pcx to png)

Tags: image, imagemagick, processing, transparent

My goal is to convert a pcx image to png. The pcx image has transparent background and white lines\sketch.

I tried converting it using the below:

```
magick convert abc.pcx abc.png
magick convert abc.pcx -flatten abc.png
magick convert abc.pcx -background white -flatten abc.png
```

I also tried doing it programmatically (which is my ultimate goal) but nothing

```
using (var magickImage = new MagickImage(file))
{
magickImage.Format = MagickFormat.Png;

 // this one kind of works, it does make the background
 // transparent but the lines\sketch has white lines and black
 // (only at the sketch)
 // where we need transparent background and black lines\sketch
 // magickImage.FloodFill(MagickColors.Transparent, 0, 0);

var filePng = Path.ChangeExtension(file, ".png");
magickImage.Write(filePng);
}
```

FYI - when the .pcx image is opened in adobe express shows correctly - transparent background with black lines.
When opened in ImageMagick (IMDisplay) shows black background with white lines.

Here is the link with the .pcx and the converted .png
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1x2fWswUFWL6hrLRCW1zuztC1Cry-QDqY/view?usp=sharing

Any ideas what i need to do?

Comment: The syntax `magick convert ...` is almost never what you want - see https://stackoverflow.com/a/61208844/2836621 Please share your PCX file for better assistance - you'll likely need to use Google Drive or Dropbox.

Comment: Updated with the link. Thank you.

Comment: I opened your PCX file in Photoshop and it is black lines on white background. There is no transparency. You can achieve the same result with `magick test.pcx -negate test.png`

Comment: If you open it on Illustrator it is not a white background. It is transparent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here how this can be achieved:

```
using (var magickImage = new MagickImage(file))
{
   magickImage.Format = MagickFormat.Png;
   magickImage.Negate();
   magickImage.Transparent(MagickColors.White);

   var filePng = Path.ChangeExtension(file, ".png");                    
   magickImage.Write(filePng);
}
```