# Crop the result of a tile?

Tags: imagemagick

I'm dumping images from an old game, and for whatever reason they come divided in chunks of 64x64. I tile them to make up the 640x512 picture, fix the alpha, and then I need to crop off some dummy pixel rows from the bottom so that it is 640x480.

Thing is, I can't seem to make the crop work correctly. How do I make the crop apply over the result of this, and have it all be in a single command?

`magick montage -tile 10x8 -geometry +0+0 -alpha off *.png out.png`

I'm on 7.1.0 on W11.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's make 4 circular gradients for illustration:

```
magick -size 100x100 radial-gradient:magenta-black -duplicate 3 %d.png
```

Here they are:

```
-rw-r--r--     1 mark  staff     20307 12 Mar 08:28 0.png
-rw-r--r--     1 mark  staff     20307 12 Mar 08:28 1.png
-rw-r--r--     1 mark  staff     20307 12 Mar 08:28 2.png
-rw-r--r--     1 mark  staff     20307 12 Mar 08:28 3.png
```

And they all look the same:

[image]

---

If you do this:

```
magick montage -geometry +0+0 ?.png result.png
```

You get:

[image]

---

If you do this:

```
magick montage -geometry +0+0 ?.png -crop 50x50+0+0 result.png
```

You get the following and you can see it did the cropping ***prior*** to montaging:

[image]

---

But if you montage the images together and send the result in a MIFF *"Magick Image File Format"* (which can contain any number of layers and any number of bit-depths) to a further instance of `magick` and crop it there:

```
magick montage -geometry +0+0 ?.png MIFF:- | magick MIFF:- -crop 200x125+0+0 result.png
```

You get:

[image]

Note that you can, in this instance, replace `MIFF:-` with `PNG:-` if you don't understand the need for it - it would come into its own with a 64-bit TIFF for example, where an intermediate 16-bit PNG would be unable to retain all information between the two stages.

---

I'm hoping you asked for a single command because you don't want to write to disk, although you didn't say why, and if so, this solution achieves that. If the reason was different, please explain and I will provide a different solution.

---

If you really, really only want to use a single process for some reason, you can use a *"magick script"* like this.

First put all the commands you want in a script file, and name it say `croppedMontage.mgk`:

```
( 0.png 1.png +append )     # append 0.png and 1.png across page to make a row
( 2.png 3.png +append )     # append 2.png and 3.png across page to make a row
-append                     # vertically stack all previously created rows down the page
-crop 200x125+0+0           # crop result of stacking all rows
-write result.png
```

Then invoke it with:

```
magick -script croppedMontage.mgk
```

[image]

Note that you *could* do the above on the command-line without a script, but I didn't do that because the number of files you have is a bit unwieldy and the quoting is ugly. It *would* look like this though:

```
magick \
   \( 0.png 1.png +append \) \
   \( 2.png 3.png +append \) \
   -append -crop 200x125+0+0 result.png
```

Note that quoting is different in Windows where you want:

```
magick ^
   ( 0.png 1.png +append ) ^
   ( 2.png 3.png +append ) ^
   -append -crop 200x125+0+0 result.png
```

So that's maybe yet another reason to prefer the script approach.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the thorough explanation!  

Sadly, I'm not sure if I misunderstood or I'm doing it wrong, but doing 
`magick montage -tile 10x8 -geometry +0+0 -alpha off *.png MIFF:- | magick MIFF:- -crop 640x480+0+0 out.png`  

gets me this error  
`magick.exe: unable to read image data "C:/Users/Kuro/AppData/Local/Temp/magick-wOJGqixHCxMjDjwFiGQdbV-5EscK26jQ" @ error/miff.c/ReadMIFFImage/1604.`  

As for why I wanted to do it in one command, yeah, I wanted to avoid writing to disc, but also to figure out why it wasn't behaving like expected.

Comment: Mmmm... are you using Powershell? It corrupts binary data. Can you try CMD32.EXE? And/or replace MIFF:- with PNG:-

Comment: Or, you can force *"plain"* mode (uncompressed, non-binary) PPM file with `magick montage -geometry +0+0 ?.png -compress none PPM:- | magick PPM:- -crop 200x125+0+0 result.png`

Comment: I was using powershell, yeah. The plain mode makes it work. Thanks!!