# Imagemagick - resize images and overlay to another image

Tags: imagemagick

I want to do the following with `ImageMagick`:

All files from the "before" folder with the extension `.png` should be reduced to a maximum width of 1100 pixels and a height of 800 pixels, keeping the aspect ratio. Then put the reduced image on the main image `background.jpg` and save it in the "after" folder under the same name as it had in the "before" folder.

So far I have something like this. It works for a single file:

```
magick convert before/image1.png -resize 1100x800^> before/image1_resized.png
magick convert -gravity center -composite background.jpg before/image1_resized.png after/image1.png
```

How to write it in 1 line and keep the original filenames?

Comment: You didn't state your OS. Also, `magick convert ...` is almost never correct, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/61208844/2836621

Comment: My OS is Windows.

Answer (score 0):

I don't use or know Windows or its arcane `CMD32.EXE`, but as nobody is answering you I will have an attempt to see if I can get you started. Make backups and work on copies as I am just guessing...

I find it generally easier to actually go into the source directory to do the processing because you get passed all the filenames without any prefixed directory rather than getting the prefix of the input directory and having to then change it to create the output directory. I mean I'd rather make `../after/filename.jpg` starting from `filename.jpg` instead of starting with `before/filename.jpg` and then trying somehow to replace `before` with `after`.

I read about `for` [here](https://ss64.com/nt/for2.html), so I guess you need something like:

```
MKDIR after
CD input
FOR %G IN (IMAGE*.PNG) DO (
    magick %G -resize 1100x800^> -gravity centre background.jpg +swap -compose over -composite ../after/%G
)
```

You may need double percent signs if in a BATCH file - I don't know. You may be able to omit the parentheses around the `magick` command and do it all on one line - I don't know.

---

As it stands, the command above loads the overlying image, resizes, then loads the background ***and swaps the order*** so the background is underneath, then composites. It is possible to load the background first, then load and alter just the foreground by putting the resizing command in parentheses, and then compositing. That will look something like this:

```
magick background.jpg ( foreground.png -resize ... ) -compose overlay -composite result.png
```

Take your pick, both should work.