# Rails: ImageMagick "`identify -format" command fails in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, imagemagick, minimagick

I'm using Rails with `mini_magick` and my code fails on call of `image.size` with such exception:

```
`identify -format %m %w %h %b /tmp/RackMultipart20231025-217-shzlwd.png[0]` failed with error:
  > image.size
```

Recently I updated my ruby version to 3.1 and Rails to 7.0, so it could be somehow connected with it. Also using mini_magick version 4.11.0.

Any hints how to fix this?

Comment: I imagine you'd need to double-quote the *format* specification `.... -format "%m %w %h %b" ...`

Comment: Also, if using v7 **ImageMagick**, the syntax has changed and you need to use `magick identify ...`. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/61208844/2836621

Comment: Is your MiniMagick trying to use IM 7 and you only have IM 6 installed (or vice-versa)?

Comment: @MarkSetchell `identify -format "%m %w %h %b"` it's not my code - it's just error message from trace (seems like ImageMagick code).

Comment: @fmw42 Thanks for a hint, it could be a possible reason, since this bug reproducible only on other env, which was setup on Heroku where I have imagemagick 6. And on my local machine there is no such issue and I have imagemagick 7. Currently I'm trying to find a way to update imagemagick on Heroku... seems like it's not so easy task. :)

Comment: Thank you for help guys, it was connected with ImageMagick version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, the issue really connected with ImageMagick (IM) version.
My IM version was 6.9.10-23.

Old IM crashes on PNGs > 16000 width:
https://github.com/ImageMagick/ImageMagick/issues/2732

Upgrade IM to version 6.9.11 can fix this issue (if you are using Heroku, migrate to heroku-22 will automatically update IM version).

PS: Resizing image can be as workaround, if there is no possibility to update IM itself.

Comment: Thanks for writing up the solution and sharing it back with the SO community.