After successful install of ImageMagick w. Mac Ports it doesn't work
ImageMagick is installed, but I can’t get it to work.
Mac OS 10.14 Mojave, ImageMagick 6.9.13
# port install imagemagick
--->  Computing dependencies for ImageMagick
--->  Cleaning ImageMagick
--->  Scanning binaries for linking errors
--->  No broken files found.
--->  No broken ports found.
# magick -v
sh: magick: command not found

There have been installed a bunch of commands, but how can I use them?
  /opt/local/bin/animate
  /opt/local/bin/compare
  /opt/local/bin/composite
  /opt/local/bin/conjure
  /opt/local/bin/convert
  /opt/local/bin/display
  /opt/local/bin/identify
  /opt/local/bin/import
  /opt/local/bin/mogrify
  /opt/local/bin/montage
  /opt/local/bin/stream

OK, I can use these commandds directly, but not using
magick -convert
I also did a # port contents ImageMagick but it’s a long list and I don’t know how to attach this file.
Thanks a lot for any help!

This is actually a stupid question. I didn’t know ImageMagick before and found out only afterwards that I need to call the commands directly. I was assuming — having seen from some examples that I saw — that the syntax is:
magick -[option]

However, in my case I can only call these directly, like this:
convert -density 204x98 -resize 1728x1186 -compress ...

I leave this post in, maybe it can help someone else.

convert, mogrify, compare are all "old" version 6 behaviour. The current v7 syntax, which has been in use for many years is magick. It is all explained here... https://stackoverflow.com/a/61208844/2836621

You should generally use the proper Imagemagick 6/7 syntax, which is convert/magick input settings operators output.  Do not use normal Unix syntax with the input and output at the end.

For novices, see
http://www.imagemagick.org/discourse-server/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=9620
http://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-processing.php
https://imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php
http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/reference.html
http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/
https://github.com/ImageMagick/usage-markdown
https://imagemagick.org/script/porting.php#cli
https://legacy.imagemagick.org/discourse-server/index.php

ImageMagick 7 is also available on MacPorts:  https://ports.macports.org/port/ImageMagick7/details/
